# Creating an Array of different Kinetic.Image(), image.getImage() undefined?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using `javascriptKinetic`.

```
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

I need to create an array of `Kinetic.Images()` each with a different image.
Here is the my code.

```
var imagesRef = ["cNote.gif","dNote.gif","eNote.gif","fNote.gif","gNote.gif","aNote.gif","cNote.gif","cSharpdFlat.gif","dSharpeFlat.gif","fSharpgFlat.gif","gSharpaFlat.gif","aSharpbFlat.gif"];                                                                        
    var imageObjs=[] ;
    var imageObj;
    var images=[];
    var image;
    var imageX = 0;
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  function drawImages(){
  for(i=0;i<11;i++){
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObjs[i] = imageObj;
    imageObjs[i].src= imagePath + imagesRef[i];

    alert(imageObjs[i].src);
    imageObjs[i].onload = function(){
      alert("imageOnload has been called");
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
           x:imageX,
           y:0,
           image:imageObjs[i],
           width:75,
           height:75,
           stroke:'black',
           strokeWidth:1,
           strokeEnabled:true
        });

        alert("image has been created");
        alert(image.getImage());
    images[i] = image;
    layer.add(images[i]);
    imageX += 75;
    layer.draw();
    }

  }
   }
stage.add(layer);

</script>

 <input type="button" onclick="drawImages();"id="submit" value="submit" />
```

When the Button is clicked it should load the images.
But instead only the stroke of the `kinetic.image` is being loaded

So what I see is a row of rectangles with no image inside like its supposed to.
The alert of the `imageObjs[i].src` fires for each time it iterates through the loop before the alert "image has been created". When I try `alert(image.getImage())` I get undefined.

Comment: I don't remember very well, but if you want to store elements dynamically on a JavaScript array, you should use push function: `imageObjs.push(imageObj);` Hope it helps.

Comment: I am pretty sure imageObjs[i] = imageObj; would work the same way as imageObjs.push(imageObj); Although I did try the switch and still no luck, im still searching though thanks for the comment i have done another instance that works similar ways but with rectangles instead and it seemed to work

Comment: Mmmm sorry to read that :-/  Another thought: why don't you use the `imageObj` instead of `imageObjs[i]`? I think you can store the `imageObj` object at the end of the for loop, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be because you did not define variable `imagePath`.

Comment: I must have accidently deleted that line when making this. i do declare imagePath = './images/'; It seems like imageObjs[i].onload doesn't fire until all of the imageObjs[i].src = imagePath + imageRef[i]; have looped through till the end.

Comment: Fixed issue was preloading images

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing you are but locally?  When you say the problem was preloading how did you fix it exactly?